# SharePoint 2010 Save Daily Versions / View Daily Versions

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to have SharePoint automatically save a copy of its list (spreadsheet) to a file at the end of the day?

My understanding is that versions are just for backup and are triggered by a single item changing.

Right now we have an excel spreadsheet that we work on each day adding new items and working on them and updating them - then the next day we copy the previous days document and rename it to todays date.  Apparently this is for auditing purposes to view activity between different days.

I would like to move to SharePoint since we have a SharePoint 3.0 site on our intranet already setup and I have created a custom list that does everything else but do not see how to have these automatically exported without someone manually saving them.

On a side note, at some point we are moving to SharePoint 2010 so I dont know if that will give us what we need.

EDIT:  I think I should be more specific that I want to save the entire contents of the list, not just version a single item.  SharePoint seems to only version item by item and not the entire list.  Not sure if there is some automated export of list data option available.

Answer (score 0):

Well, SharePoint you can enable document versioning in SharePoint - you can check all versions and see who an when has modified them.

In case you really need to copy some files, maybe some workflow could help